# How to update Kendo Grid if database has new row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I'm making an MVC ASP.NET application where I want to visualize data by using Kendo. 
I can already load data from the database, but now I want to automate this when there is a new row then the grid has to refresh. But what is the correct way to do this?

My grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<NFC.Areas.Admin.ViewModels.Grids.ObjectDetectionGrid>()
  .Name("grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(c => c.Id)
        .Width(100)
        .MinScreenWidth(1020);
      columns.Bound(c => c.DetectionTime)
        .Format("{0:d-M-yyyy H:mm:ss}")
        .MinScreenWidth(1500);
      columns.Bound(c => c.Score)
        .MinScreenWidth(1500);
      columns.Bound(c => c.Name)
        .MinScreenWidth(1500);
      columns.Bound(c => c.Id)
        .Title("Image")
        .ClientTemplate("<img class='img-responsive' src='Detections/GetImage?Id=#: Id #' />");
  })
  .Sortable()
  .Pageable(x => x.PageSizes(new List<object> { 10, 20, 50, 100, 250, 500, "all" }).Refresh(false))
  .Filterable()
  .Sortable()
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Ajax()
      .Model(model => {
          model.Id(p => p.Id);
      })
      .Sort(s => s.Add(x => x.Id).Descending())
      .Events(events => events.Error("kendoGrid_ErrorHandler"))
      .Read(read => read.Action("KendoGrid_Read", "Detections"))
  )
)
```

My controller read function:

```
 public ActionResult KendoGrid_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        IQueryable<ObjectDetectionGrid> detections = db.ObjectDetections.Select(x => new ObjectDetectionGrid()
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            DetectionTime = x.DetectionTime,
            Name = x.Name,
            Score = x.Score
        });

        return Json(detections.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
```

Hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: You need to either use Ajax requests or sockets to achieve that server-to-client kind of sync  feature

Comment: Demos of live-updating grids: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/signalr or https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/web-socket